# How to make precise holes in Eagle

Tags: eaglecad

I need to create 3 circles in Layer 20 in eagle, of witch one should be in the center of my board and have a diameter of 10 mm and the other 2 should have  a diameter of 4,8 mm. The two circles should be symmetrical spaced from the circle in the middle (the one that is 10 mm) and the distance from center of either one of the circles to the one in the center should be 40 mm, also all the centers of the circles should be on (x= z, y=0).

Thanks! 
Mihai

Comment: People used to use guns but nowadays it's frowned upon and not very accurate anyway. I'm referring to your title of course.

Comment: You can type in exact coordinates and sizes using the 'Hole' command.  Or with a part using the 'move' command

Comment: I don't think that seeedstudio uses guns to make holes in PCB...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you right click on the part / via or any object in the eagle pcb router, you can access a "properties window", you can here enter the exact coordinate of the object.

[image]

You just have to do the math and then enter the position. I'll let you do the math part, I'm pretty lazy...